# What do you call a word that share the same theme as another word?

Tags: word-request

I am wondering if there's an adjective for qualifying an object as having the same theme as another word? For example, birds and crocodile share the same theme (animal), likewise, cissing and colorist share the same theme (arts). Is there such an adjective? If not can you think of a phrase or a compound word?

For example:

> Cissing and colorist are ___.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly *analogous*? This means that two items are not the same or interchangeable but have something in common and are comparable in some respects. For example, a brain and a computer are sometimes said to be analogous - they are very different, one is organic, the other a machine; one is capable of independent thought, the other has to be programmed - yet they both perform calculations and operate in binary, so they are comparable on some levels.

Your example of a bird and a crocodile certainly fit this, but "cissing" is (apparently - I had to look it up) when paint fails to adhere to a surface. This isn't really *comparable* with a colourist, and yet a colourist or artist may well be familiar with it. You could perhaps say that they are *related* or *interrelated*?

You could just fall back on the word *synonymous*. As well as referring to interchangeable words, a secondary definition of this means "closely associated with". If you are trying to say that "cissing" is something you would talk about or mention alongside the occupation of an artist or colourist then "synonymous" works just fine.